# Retrieving newest item when using group by and where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very difficult situation with a SQL statment which i cant figure out how to solve it,although i have searched SO(and here [Get the newest entry before a GROUP BY query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114873/get-the-newest-entry-before-a-group-by-query))

I have a table:

```
id  date                from_name   to_name     from_id     to_id       message
1   2013-08-29 07:20:00 John        Maria       1234        4321        hi!
2   2013-08-28 05:20:00 Justin      Helen       1234        5678        Where ru?
3   2013-08-29 08:21:00 Helen       Dude        5678        8765        Good!
4   2013-08-27 02:20:00 Jesus       Aliko       9876        9988        where?
5   2013-08-26 02:20:00 Jesus       Aliko       9876        9988        what?
```

Normally i would do `group by` with this:

`SELECT id,date,from_id,from_name,to_name,message FROM messages where to_id='9876' group by from_id order by date desc`

and give me the following result:
`5 2013-08-26 02:20:00 Jesus       Aliko       9876        9988        what?`
which is not the latest(newest) message of Jesus to Aliko.How can i group by with the latest-newest entries?

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: What platform are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would give you what you want:

```
select *
from messages 
where to_id='9876'
  and date = (select max(date) from messages where to_id='9876')
```

Comment: Thanks,it did the job!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,date,from_id,from_name,to_name,message 
FROM messages m1 
WHERE to_id='9876' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM messages m2 WHERE m2.to_id = m1.to_id and m2.date > m1.date)
```